# Getting X Y co-ordinates from Path Object

Tags: android, android-canvas

I'm developing finger paint type of application . i want to exactly track the path object.here what I mean is want to get x y co-ordinates from path object for comparison.Is there any ideal method like this?

```
Path.getX(I);
Path.getY(I);
```

how to check Path object  has particular x and y co-ordinates in it ?

Comment: I know u have path.IsEmpty to indicate whether it has coordinates or not, but not sure how to get the coordinates themselves :)

Comment: yes we can check that using IsEmpty. but i want to get exactly co-ordinates

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could save your path objects in a arraylist and from there you could compare the x and y coordinates.

Comment: yes i can save the objects and iterating through the path object  .but what about getting x and y from path objects .